# Compare two files, show lines in file1 but not in file2

Tags: command-line, files, output

Let's say I have two files - file1 and file2. I want to compare those files, but output only lines that are in file1 and not in file2. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. [Sort](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/sort.1.html) each file
2. Use [comm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/comm.1.html) with the -23 option to show what's not in common, only the lines in file A which are not in file B; `comm -23 fileA fileB`